# Searching Elements of a List

Tags: python, list

I am trying to search a array of previous usernames used in a game, for the username currently used by the gamer (allowing all the previous game scores under the username to be displayed). This list has been imported from an external text file.

```
for x in range(0, len(lis)):
    if username == lis[x]:
        print "yes"
    print lis[x]
```

Here for example, the username could be "Jack". Even though multiple elements in lis have the value "Jack" (verified by printing all the values of the list through 'print lis[x]'), "yes" is never printed to show this.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Try printing the raw values of the list; if it is read from a file there is a good chance you are comparing `Jack` with `Jack\n` and of course that won't match.

Comment: Try calling lis[x].strip() to get rid of the trailing newline/whitespace

Comment: (sidenote) You can check if an object is in a list simpler using the in-keyword: `if username in lis: print("yes")`. Also, if you plan to check for this type of thing many times, consider using a set.

Comment: What Burhan said. How are you reading the list? There are standard ways to read lines from a text file into a list that strip off unwanted spaces & newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for usernameTest in lis:
   if username == usernameTest.strip():
        print "yes"
    print lis[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if username in lis:
```

Should do the trick of searching through a list

If the code you have written is not working, check if the strings are formatted the same way

```
if username.strip().lower() == lis[x].strip().lower():
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is what you meant but at least this prints yes:

```
lis = ["Jack","Rose", "Joe", "Franz"]
username = "Joe"
for x in range(0, len(lis)):
if username == lis[x]:
    print ("yes")
```